# Buttons stop working between 1199 and 768px

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am running into some weird behavior. When my screen is resized anywhere between 1199 and 768 my top four buttons are unable to be chosen. But any sizes not in that range then when you click a button it shows the correct divs and all. What must I do to activate those buttons in those sizes?

https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/308/

```
<!-- ****PROPERTY ID #1**** -->

    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <label>1. SEARCH PROPERTIES BY CLICKING <u>ONE</u> OF THE FOLLOWING BUTTONS:</label>
    </div>

    <div id="searchoptions">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="accountNumber" name="accountNumber" value="accountNumber">PROPERTY ID</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="name" name="name" value="name">OWNER NAME</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="location" name="location" value="location">PROPERTY ADDRESS</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="billingAddress" name="billingAddress" value="billingAddress">BILLING ADDRESS</button>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- ****SEARCH OPTIONS #2**** -->

<!-- ****Property ID**** -->
<div id="propertyidchoice"> 
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <label>2. ENTER THE PROPERTY ID NUMBER AND SELECT TAX YEAR AND PAID STATUS:<span style="color:red;">&nbsp;* is a required field</span></label>
    </div>

    <div id="propertyidsearch">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="required-field">
              <input type="text" name="searchValue" maxlength="2000" size="40" value="" class="form-control input-sm margin-bottom-10" placeholder="--- Enter Property Id Here ---"> 
          </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <select name="taxYear" class="form-control input-sm margin-bottom-10">
                <option value="ALL">All Yrs.</option>
                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                <option value="2009">2009</option>
                <option value="2008">2008</option>
                <option value="2007">2007</option>
                <option value="2006">2006</option>
                <option value="2005">2005</option>
                <option value="2004">2004</option>
                <option value="2003">2003</option>
                <option value="2002">2002</option>
                <option value="2001">2001</option>
                <option value="2000">2000</option>
                <option value="1999">1999</option>
                <option value="1998">1998</option>
                <option value="1997">1997</option>
                <option value="1996">1996</option>
                <option value="1995">1995</option>
                <option value="1994">1994</option>
                <option value="1993">1993</option>
                <option value="1992">1992</option>
                <option value="1991">1991</option>
                <option value="1990">1990</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <select name="paidStatus" class="form-control input-sm margin-bottom-10"><option value="" selected="selected">All</option>
                <option value="Y">Paid</option>
                <option value="N">Unpaid</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="group" name="group">SEARCH</button>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>   

 <!-- ****Owner Name**** -->

 <div id="ownernamechoice" style="display:none;">   
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <label>2. ENTER THE OWNER'S NAME AND SELECT TAX YEAR AND PAID STATUS:<span style="color:red;">&nbsp;* is a required field</span></label>
    </div>

    <div id="propertyidsearch">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="required-field">
              <input type="text" name="searchValue" maxlength="2000" size="40" value="" class="form-control input-sm margin-bottom-10" placeholder="--- LastName, FirstName ---">        
          </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <select name="taxYear" class="form-control input-sm margin-bottom-10">
                <option value="ALL">All Yrs.</option>
                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                <option value="2009">2009</option>
                <option value="2008">2008</option>
                <option value="2007">2007</option>
                <option value="2006">2006</option>
                <option value="2005">2005</option>
                <option value="2004">2004</option>
                <option value="2003">2003</option>
                <option value="2002">2002</option>
                <option value="2001">2001</option>
                <option value="2000">2000</option>
                <option value="1999">1999</option>
                <option value="1998">1998</option>
                <option value="1997">1997</option>
                <option value="1996">1996</option>
                <option value="1995">1995</option>
                <option value="1994">1994</option>
                <option value="1993">1993</option>
                <option value="1992">1992</option>
                <option value="1991">1991</option>
                <option value="1990">1990</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <select name="paidStatus" class="form-control input-sm margin-bottom-10"><option value="" selected="selected">All</option>
                <option value="Y">Paid</option>
                <option value="N">Unpaid</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="group" name="group">SEARCH</button>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div> 

 <!-- **** Property Address **** -->

 <div id="propertyaddresschoice" style="display:none;"> 
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <label>2. ENTER THE PROPERTY ADDRESS AND SELECT TAX YEAR AND PAID STATUS:<span style="color:red;">&nbsp;* is a required field</span></label>
    </div>

    <div id="propertyidsearch">
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <label>House #</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm margin-bottom-10">        
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <label>Unit</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm margin-bottom-10">        
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label>Street<span style="color:red;">&nbsp;*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm margin-bottom-10">        
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <label>Direction</label>
            <select name="propertySearchCritera.location.streetDirection" class="form-control input-sm margin-bottom-10">
                <option value="" selected="selected">&nbsp;</option>        
                <option value="E">E</option>
                <option value="N">N</option>
                <option value="NE">NE</option> 
                <option value="NW">NW</option>  
                <option value="S">S</option>
                <option value="SE">SE</option>
                <option value="SW">SW</option>
                <option value="W">W</option>
            </select>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <label>Suffix 1</label>
            <select name="propertySearchCritera.location.streetType1" class="form-control input-sm margin-bottom-10">
                <option value="" selected="selected">&nbsp;</option>
                <option value="AVE">AVE</option>
                <option value="BLVD">BLVD</option>
                <option value="CIR">CIR</option>
                <option value="CT">CT</option>
                <option value="CV">CV</option>
                <option value="DR">DR</option>
                <option value="GLN">GLN</option>
                <option value="HWY">HWY</option>
                <option value="LN">LN</option>
                <option value="LOOP">LOOP</option>
                <option value="PIKE">PIKE</option>
                <option value="PKY">PKY</option>
                <option value="PL">PL</option>
                <option value="PLZ">PLZ</option>
                <option value="RD">RD</option>
                <option value="RUN">RUN</option>
                <option value="ST">ST</option>
                <option value="TER">TER</option>
                <option value="TRCE">TRCE</option>
                <option value="TRL">TRL</option>
                <option value="WALK">WALK</option>
                <option value="WAY">WAY</option>
                <option value="XING">XING</option>
            </select>        
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <label>Suffix 2</label>
            <select name="propertySearchCritera.location.streetType2" class="form-control input-sm margin-bottom-10">
                <option value="" selected="selected">&nbsp;</option>
                <option value="AVE">AVE</option>
                <option value="BLVD">BLVD</option>
                <option value="CIR">CIR</option>
                <option value="CT">CT</option>
                <option value="CV">CV</option>
                <option value="DR">DR</option>
                <option value="GLN">GLN</option>
                <option value="HWY">HWY</option>
                <option value="LN">LN</option>
                <option value="LOOP">LOOP</option>
                <option value="PIKE">PIKE</option>
                <option value="PKY">PKY</option>
                <option value="PL">PL</option>
                <option value="PLZ">PLZ</option>
                <option value="RD">RD</option>
                <option value="RUN">RUN</option>
                <option value="ST">ST</option>
                <option value="TER">TER</option>
                <option value="TRCE">TRCE</option>
                <option value="TRL">TRL</option>
                <option value="WALK">WALK</option>
                <option value="WAY">WAY</option>
                <option value="XING">XING</option>
            </select>        
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label>Tax Year</label>
            <select name="taxYear" class="form-control input-sm margin-bottom-10">
                <option value="ALL">All Yrs.</option>
                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                <option value="2009">2009</option>
                <option value="2008">2008</option>
                <option value="2007">2007</option>
                <option value="2006">2006</option>
                <option value="2005">2005</option>
                <option value="2004">2004</option>
                <option value="2003">2003</option>
                <option value="2002">2002</option>
                <option value="2001">2001</option>
                <option value="2000">2000</option>
                <option value="1999">1999</option>
                <option value="1998">1998</option>
                <option value="1997">1997</option>
                <option value="1996">1996</option>
                <option value="1995">1995</option>
                <option value="1994">1994</option>
                <option value="1993">1993</option>
                <option value="1992">1992</option>
                <option value="1991">1991</option>
                <option value="1990">1990</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <label>Status</label>
            <select name="paidStatus" class="form-control input-sm margin-bottom-10"><option value="" selected="selected">All</option>
                <option value="Y">Paid</option>
                <option value="N">Unpaid</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <button type="submit" class="btn-u btn-default btn-fix input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="group" name="group">SEARCH</button>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

 <!-- **** Billing Address **** -->

 <div id="billingaddresschoice" style="display:none;">  
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <label>2. ENTER THE BILLING ADDRESS AND SELECT TAX YEAR AND PAID STATUS:<span style="color:red;">&nbsp;* is a required field</span></label>
    </div>

    <div id="propertyidsearch">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="required-field">
              <input type="text" name="searchValue" maxlength="2000" size="40" value="" class="form-control input-sm margin-bottom-10" placeholder="--- Enter Billing Address Here ---">        
          </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <select name="taxYear" class="form-control input-sm margin-bottom-10">
                <option value="ALL">All Yrs.</option>
                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                <option value="2009">2009</option>
                <option value="2008">2008</option>
                <option value="2007">2007</option>
                <option value="2006">2006</option>
                <option value="2005">2005</option>
                <option value="2004">2004</option>
                <option value="2003">2003</option>
                <option value="2002">2002</option>
                <option value="2001">2001</option>
                <option value="2000">2000</option>
                <option value="1999">1999</option>
                <option value="1998">1998</option>
                <option value="1997">1997</option>
                <option value="1996">1996</option>
                <option value="1995">1995</option>
                <option value="1994">1994</option>
                <option value="1993">1993</option>
                <option value="1992">1992</option>
                <option value="1991">1991</option>
                <option value="1990">1990</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <select name="paidStatus" class="form-control input-sm margin-bottom-10"><option value="" selected="selected">All</option>
                <option value="Y">Paid</option>
                <option value="N">Unpaid</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="group" name="group">SEARCH</button>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are required to show a minimal example of the markup that shows the problem here, not a third party site that can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one in the future. You only show HTML and no CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `searchoptions` div has 4 floated elements and no clear, and so its height is `0px`. The div below it is being moved up *over* it, and thus it covers it, not allowing you to click anything.

Include a clear element in your `searchoptions` div:

```
<div id="searchoptions">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        ...
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could use pseudo-elements to clear it without the need for the extra `<div>`:

```
#searchoptions::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right, any time this happens to me, first thing I do is place my mouse over one of the unresponsive button, and try to inspect it, using the browser DOM inspector. (right-click, select "Inspect element") Usually, the problem is another element on the page has moved "on top" of your buttons...

Sure enough, it seems it is the row below it that floats on top of it.

All you need to do is make sure your row with buttons is in fact a Bootstrap row:

```
<div id="searchoptions" class="row">
```

Which will clear the float on your columns, and give back that row's height.

Hope this helps!